# Как сделать градиент поверх картинки

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-xml

я пытаюсь сделать кнопку для игры, создал для неё градиент и хочу сделать картинку стоящую за градиентом.
Кнопка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="55dp"
    android:width="70dp"
    android:viewportWidth="70.0"
    android:viewportHeight="55.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@drawable/$neon_news__0" <! Здесь ссылаюсь на неон -->
        android:pathData="M10,1.5L59,1.5A8.5,8.5 0,0 1,67.5 10L67.5,45A8.5,8.5 0,0 1,59 53.5L10,53.5A8.5,8.5 0,0 1,1.5 45L1.5,10A8.5,8.5 0,0 1,10 1.5z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M10,1.5L59,1.5A8.5,8.5 0,0 1,67.5 10L67.5,45A8.5,8.5 0,0 1,59 53.5L10,53.5A8.5,8.5 0,0 1,1.5 45L1.5,10A8.5,8.5 0,0 1,10 1.5z"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFDA500"
        android:strokeWidth="3.0" />
</vector>
```

Код неона

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:angle="0.0"
    android:type="0"
    android:startX="43.0"
    android:startY="0.0"
    android:endX="43.0"
    android:endY="97.0">
    <item
        android:color="#00D27E00"
        android:offset="0.0" />
    <item
        android:color="#FFD27E00"
        android:offset="1.0" />
</gradient>
```

Помогите пожалуйста, я не знаю как это реализовать. Всё, что я пробовал делать не работает.

Comment: Вам поможет Layer List Drawable.